# Why should I avoid writing queries directly against a replicated table (subscriber side)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

We have a transactionally replicated database.  We're trying to decide whether to:

1. Write my application's queries directly against those replicated tables (on subscriber side) OR
2. Create jobs to pull data out of those tables, and write queries against those data?

Is there a reason not to do #1?

Rephrased question: if you had to query against a replicated db, what criteria would you use to decide that it's OK to do #1?

Comment: This question seems to be outside the scope of stackoverflow. The only responses you will get are going to be opinion based and not directly related to programming issues. The other challenge is that before anybody can offer any opinion there are more questions than answers. Are these queries only selects? Is the data changing frequently? etc...

Comment: Are you going to do updates on the replicated tables?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Well I'm looking for a guideline. Since this is a replicated db that contains many tables, some are updated frequently, some are not. So I guess the answer is "depends", that no hard and fast rule exists? The key is avoiding lock contention between updates and selects, correct? My colleague is saying always do #2. So I'm looking for some supporting information.

Comment: Unless two way replication is being used (mistakenly) updating a subscription article can break the subscription warranting a new snapshot generation.